# How do I call multiple super constructors in Scala?

Tags: scala, inheritance, constructor

For example, `Exception` in Java has four constructors, and inheriting exceptions call every constructor:

```java
class MyException extends Exception {
    public MyException() { super() };
    public MyException(String message) { super(message) };
    public MyException(Throwable cause) { super(cause) };
    public MyException(String message, Throwable cause) { super(message, cause) };
}
```

In Scala, I can call a parent's constructor, but only one:

```scala
class MyException(message: String = "", cause: Throwable = null) extends Exception(message, cause)
```

This has four versions of the constructor (due to default values), but only the most generic super constructor is called. How can I call the other super constructors in Scala? Different constructors may do different things (probably not in the case of `Exception`, but in general), so I would like to be able to call them.

Comment: See also https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/domain-modeling-tools.html#auxiliary-constructors